# Some of my mouse buttons are not working in Excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, logitech-mouse

I am using Excel as part of Microsoft 365 Office 16. I am using a Logitech G502 mouse. The regular functionality of the mouse is working (right/left click & scroll up/down) but any of the "extra" buttons/features are not working in Excel ONLY. Tilt scroll and the side buttons which are mapped to volume up/down are not working at all. I have other buttons mapped to copy/paste and "enter" that are working though. It just seems like excel doesn't like tilt scroll or volume up/down all of a sudden. It was working fine yesterday. Additionally, I will say it works in other Microsoft 365 applications such as Word or OneNote.

Comment: Rather than using the huge Logitech button-mapping driver, I've found the free X-Mouse Button Control, https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm, to be compatible with more applications.

Comment: I downloaded and set this up trying both the mouse tilt and window scroll commands mapped to the tilt buttons but neither worked. Curiously when I was using the tilt functions, they were not registering in the application but when I switched to a different window they would register. This still only happens in Excel and nothing else.

Comment: I have the same exact mouse, but no issues thast I've noticed while using Excel?  Are you using O365 Excel?  Have you tried using, e.g., AHK instead for your mouse bindings?

Comment: @Arctiic I have tried an alternative binding program as suggested by DrMoishe Pippik but that didnt help either. It used to work just fine in Excel as well as all other programs but now it does not work only in Excel. I am using O365 Excel. I still havent found a solution but curiously if I dont have the window selected or "active" I can mouseover and the tilt scroll will work. It only doesnt work when the window is active for some reason...